# Rational form is conserved under field extension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a field $F$ be an extension of a field $F_0$. If $T$ is a linear operator over a finite dimension vector space $V$ over both $F_0$ and $F$, how to prove that $T$ has the same rational form over $F_0$ and $F$?

Comment: I think something is missing, or plainly wrong, here: we have $\;T\in \text{End}_{F_0}(V)\;$ . Since $\;F_0\subset F\;$ , it could even be $\;V\;$ is **not** a vector space over $\;F\;$ ...

Comment: @Timbuc, I've edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have figured out. Just leave a comment for future reference. $M$ is similar to a rational form $A$ means there exists invertible $P$ s.t. $PMP^{-1}=A$. This is equivalent to $det(P)\neq 0$, which does not vary for larger field.